# cmbright not allowing bold and italic

Tags: fonts, formatting, bold, italic, sans-serif

I'm using the cmbright package to make the entire document (including maths) a sans-serif (as serif fonts are generally less dyslexic-friendly).

However, the document won't let me use a bold and italic at the same time. Regardless of how I nest it, it will just give me a bold font. If I remove cmbright, it works just fine, but I really don't want to have to use a serif font.

Are there any easy methods of converting the document to a sans-serif (including maths) that don't encounter this problem, or are there any ways to get around this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's a super quick example of my issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document} 
cmbright won't allow me to \textbf{bold} and \textit{italicise} my text \textbf{\textit{at the same time}}, no matter \textit{\textbf{how I nest them.}} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no boldface italic font available with cmbright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `lmodern` and `sfmath` package should help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
cmbright won't allow me to \textbf{bold} and
\textit{italicise} my text
\textbf{\textit{at the same time}},
no matter \textit{\textbf{how I nest them.}}

$2a-3B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful, but using this method, maths is still a serif. Is it possible to switch maths to be a sans-serif also?

Comment: @KierenDuffy: Solved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of sans serif families with a full range of styles is rather limited, you may get more choice if you switch to xetex or luatex and use system fonts.

This is Arial with lualatex for example

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document} 
cmbright won't allow me to \textbf{bold} and \textit{italicise} my text \textbf{\textit{at the same time}}, no matter \textit{\textbf{how I nest them.}} 
\end{document}
```